# Saving data to Postgres from AWS Lambda using Python

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import io
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event:
            s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
            bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
            key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'] 
            file_obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=key)
            file_content = file_obj['Body'].read()
            b = io.BytesIO(file_content)
            df = pd.read_excel(b)
            print(df)
```

I am trying to upload excel sheet data from s3 to amazon rds (Postgres). The above code is what I have to extract data from s3. How can I upload the data from here to postgres, Please Help.

Comment: https://www.psycopg.org/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to upload data to postgres.